# ExtJS 6 background of datefield calendar transparent

Tags: extjs

I have the strangest little problem that I cannot seem to solve. We are using the admin dashboard from Sencha and we define a datefield inside a form:

```
{
        xtype: 'fieldcontainer',
        defaultType: 'textfield',
        width: '100%',
        defaults: {
            labelWidth: 100,
            labelSeparator: '',
            submitEmptyText: false,
            margin: "3 10 0 10"
        },
        items:[
            {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'Geburtsdatum',
                name: 'geburtstag',
                format: 'd.m.Y'
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Alter',
                editable: false,
                name: 'alter'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'combobox',
                name: 'geschlecht',
                fieldLabel: 'Geschlecht',
                store: 'lookup.Geschlecht',
                queryMode: 'remote',
                displayField: 'text',
                valueField: 'id',
                editable: false
            },
            {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                fieldLabel: 'geworben am',
                name: 'geworbenAm',
                format: 'd.m.Y'
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'geworben von',
                name: 'geworbenVon'
            },
            {
                fieldLabel: 'Ehrungen',
                name: 'ehrungen'
            }
        ]
    }
```

Everything works fine with one exception: the background of the pop-up calendar is transparent: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eic6sua4y7m9n9w/Screenshot%202016-02-16%2009.00.51.png?dl=0

Any idea how to fix this? I'm not sure where to look to solve this :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you already use Sencha Cmd, a re-compile would solve the issue. Otherwise, how did you add the CSS? The CSS for the datefield menu is missing.

Comment: I'll try to re-compile. I did refresh the app a few times, which didn't seem to solve the problem.

I didn't add any CSS ... doesn't the standard extjs come with predefined CSS or is the problem that it is missing from the admin dashboard?

Comment: Awesome!!! thanks, that did it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Sencha Cmd, the CSS is compiled from SASS sources every time you build your solution.

Since browsers cannot read sass sources, the uncompiled version of your ExtJS app still has to use the compiled version of your CSS.

The CSS is compiled by concatenating together and then compiling all SASS files where path and filename correspond to a ExtJS javascript source file that is required in your ExtJS project *at the time of compilation*.

If you require other builtin Ext javascript files afterwards, the JS is loaded dynamically, but the CSS for these is not readily available, but a recompile of your app will solve this.